# formatting json data from api

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using api to extract exchange rates in json form right now the result shows like this

```
"RUB":1,"AED":0.06317,"AFN":1.5074,"ALL":2.0112,"AMD":7.0904,"ANG":0.03079,"AOA":6.9821,"ARS":2.4694,"AUD":0.02624,"AWG":0.03079,"AZN":0.02896,"BAM":0.03457,"BBD":0.0344,"BDT":1.7593,"BGN":0.03457,"BHD":0.006468,"BIF":33.7214,"BMD":0.0172,"BND":0.02457,"BOB":0.1177,"BRL":0.08918,"BSD":0.0172,"BTN":1.3948,"BWP":0.2247,"BYN":0.04456,"BZD":0.0344,"CAD":0.02333,"CDF":33.5622,"CHF":0.01691,"CLP":16.1531,"CNY":0.1225,"COP":74.4278,"CRC":10.7597,"CUP":0.4128,"CVE":1.949,"CZK":0.4341,"DJF":3.0571,"DKK":0.1319,"DOP":0.9116,"DZD":2.3957,"EGP":0.3326,"ERN":0.258,"ETB":0.8631,"EUR":0.01768,"FJD":0.03885,"FKP":0.01562,"FOK":0.1319,"GBP":0.01562,"GEL":0.04833,"GGP":0.01562,"GHS":0.1788,"GIP":0.01562,"GMD":0.9243,"GNF":141.1552,"GTQ":0.133,"GYD":3.4174,"HKD":0.1353,"HNL":0.421,"HRK":0.1332,"HTG":1.9453,"HUF":7.1365,"IDR":259.0919,"ILS":0.05999,"IMP":0.01562,"INR":1.3949,"IQD":23.8415,"IRR":717.8181,"ISK":2.4479,"JEP":0.01562,"JMD":2.5882,"JOD":0.0122,"JPY":2.4632,"KES":2.0638,"KGS":1.3947,"KHR":67.2399,"KID":0.02624,"KMF":8.6956,"KRW":24.3376,"KWD":0.005154,"KYD":0.01433,"KZT":8.2208,"LAK":273.8169,"LBP":25.9315,"LKR":6.1903,"LRD":2.6162,"LSL":0.3071,"LYD":0.08099,"MAD":0.1845,"MDL":0.331,"MGA":68.8987,"MKD":1.0155,"MMK":35.7873,"MNT":53.4153,"MOP":0.1394,"MRU":0.6182,"MUR":0.7619,"MVR":0.2625,"MWK":17.5369,"MXN":0.3462,"MYR":0.07854,"MZN":1.0862,"NAD":0.3071,"NGN":7.3194,"NIO":0.6133,"NOK":0.1814,"NPR":2.2317,"NZD":0.02979,"OMR":0.006614,"PAB":0.0172,"PEN":0.06603,"PGK":0.05993,"PHP":1.0023,"PKR":4.0715,"PLN":0.08333,"PYG":118.1834,"QAR":0.06261,"RON":0.08681,"RSD":2.0444,"RWF":18.1732,"SAR":0.06451,"SBD":0.138,"SCR":0.2232,"SDG":9.3095,"SEK":0.1934,"SGD":0.02458,"SHP":0.01562,"SLE":0.2519,"SLL":251.8519,"SOS":9.2863,"SRD":0.4595,"SSP":10.8377,"STN":0.433,"SYP":42.7533,"SZL":0.3071,"THB":0.645,"TJS":0.1733,"TMT":0.05898,"TND":0.05427,"TOP":0.04078,"TRY":0.3166,"TTD":0.1157,"TVD":0.02624,"TWD":0.5443,"TZS":39.6052,"UAH":0.6335,"UGX":64.9736,"USD":0.0172,"UYU":0.6988,"UZS":187.3274,"VES":0.1434,"VND":407.0389,"VUV":2.0628,"WST":0.04733,"XAF":11.5942,"XCD":0.04644,"XDR":0.01352,"XOF":11.5942,"XPF":2.1092,"YER":4.2578,"ZAR":0.3072,"ZMW":0.2673,"ZWL":10.0256
```

I would like to format and make it look using javascript as data is getting fetched by javascript

```
function currencyexchange(currency1){
    console.log(currency1);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/currency.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            code:currency1
            
        },
        //if user enters correct data and api gives back the data then we run success funtion
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result),null,4);

            //if status of data is ok we fetch the data from fields and put them in results table in html
            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                //fetching fields from api and showing them in html table
               $('#exchangedata').html(JSON.stringify(result['data']).replace(/['"]+/g, '').slice(1,-1));
                

            }else{
                //if the upper condition  fails
                console.log("error");
               
            }
        
        },
        //if there is no success in retrieving data from api
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            console.log("error");
            $('#txterror').html("Enter Valid Id");
        }
    });
```

Comment: That looks like if could be turned into JSON by just putting it between braces.

Comment: do you also have a html? can you please add it if you do

Comment: it is in json already but I want to style it and display it, like displaying every currecncy line by line

Comment: in html I only have a <p> tag in which it is all displaying

Comment: It's really unclear what you want it to look like, do you mean you want it to look like JSON on a HTML page, if so just do -> `JSON.stringify(data,null, '  ')`, and make sure the control your putting it into is formatted using the css `white-space: pre`, or the html `pre` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```js
// add { and } to the json string (if it's not already there) 
const data = `{ "RUB":1,"AED":0.06317,"AFN":1.5074,"ALL":2.0112,"AMD":7.0904,"ANG":0.03079,"AOA":6.9821,"ARS":2.4694,"AUD":0.02624,"AWG":0.03079,"AZN":0.02896,"BAM":0.03457,"BBD":0.0344,"BDT":1.7593,"BGN":0.03457,"BHD":0.006468,"BIF":33.7214,"BMD":0.0172,"BND":0.02457,"BOB":0.1177,"BRL":0.08918,"BSD":0.0172,"BTN":1.3948,"BWP":0.2247,"BYN":0.04456,"BZD":0.0344,"CAD":0.02333,"CDF":33.5622,"CHF":0.01691,"CLP":16.1531,"CNY":0.1225,"COP":74.4278,"CRC":10.7597,"CUP":0.4128,"CVE":1.949,"CZK":0.4341,"DJF":3.0571,"DKK":0.1319,"DOP":0.9116,"DZD":2.3957,"EGP":0.3326,"ERN":0.258,"ETB":0.8631,"EUR":0.01768,"FJD":0.03885,"FKP":0.01562,"FOK":0.1319,"GBP":0.01562,"GEL":0.04833,"GGP":0.01562,"GHS":0.1788,"GIP":0.01562,"GMD":0.9243,"GNF":141.1552,"GTQ":0.133,"GYD":3.4174,"HKD":0.1353,"HNL":0.421,"HRK":0.1332,"HTG":1.9453,"HUF":7.1365,"IDR":259.0919,"ILS":0.05999,"IMP":0.01562,"INR":1.3949,"IQD":23.8415,"IRR":717.8181,"ISK":2.4479,"JEP":0.01562,"JMD":2.5882,"JOD":0.0122,"JPY":2.4632,"KES":2.0638,"KGS":1.3947,"KHR":67.2399,"KID":0.02624,"KMF":8.6956,"KRW":24.3376,"KWD":0.005154,"KYD":0.01433,"KZT":8.2208,"LAK":273.8169,"LBP":25.9315,"LKR":6.1903,"LRD":2.6162,"LSL":0.3071,"LYD":0.08099,"MAD":0.1845,"MDL":0.331,"MGA":68.8987,"MKD":1.0155,"MMK":35.7873,"MNT":53.4153,"MOP":0.1394,"MRU":0.6182,"MUR":0.7619,"MVR":0.2625,"MWK":17.5369,"MXN":0.3462,"MYR":0.07854,"MZN":1.0862,"NAD":0.3071,"NGN":7.3194,"NIO":0.6133,"NOK":0.1814,"NPR":2.2317,"NZD":0.02979,"OMR":0.006614,"PAB":0.0172,"PEN":0.06603,"PGK":0.05993,"PHP":1.0023,"PKR":4.0715,"PLN":0.08333,"PYG":118.1834,"QAR":0.06261,"RON":0.08681,"RSD":2.0444,"RWF":18.1732,"SAR":0.06451,"SBD":0.138,"SCR":0.2232,"SDG":9.3095,"SEK":0.1934,"SGD":0.02458,"SHP":0.01562,"SLE":0.2519,"SLL":251.8519,"SOS":9.2863,"SRD":0.4595,"SSP":10.8377,"STN":0.433,"SYP":42.7533,"SZL":0.3071,"THB":0.645,"TJS":0.1733,"TMT":0.05898,"TND":0.05427,"TOP":0.04078,"TRY":0.3166,"TTD":0.1157,"TVD":0.02624,"TWD":0.5443,"TZS":39.6052,"UAH":0.6335,"UGX":64.9736,"USD":0.0172,"UYU":0.6988,"UZS":187.3274,"VES":0.1434,"VND":407.0389,"VUV":2.0628,"WST":0.04733,"XAF":11.5942,"XCD":0.04644,"XDR":0.01352,"XOF":11.5942,"XPF":2.1092,"YER":4.2578,"ZAR":0.3072,"ZMW":0.2673,"ZWL":10.0256}`;

// parse the JSON and for each entry of the parsed object create html
Object.entries(JSON.parse(data)).forEach( ([k, rate]) => 
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<div>${k}: ${rate}</div>`) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Map over the Object Entries & put a `<br/>` after every key value pair. Or, using the same method, you can just create a new element for each item.

```js
const result = {
  data: {
    RUB: 1,
    AED: 0.06317,
    AFN: 1.5074,
    ALL: 2.0112,
    AMD: 7.0904,
    ANG: 0.03079,
    AOA: 6.9821,
    ARS: 2.4694,
    AUD: 0.02624,
    AWG: 0.03079,
    AZN: 0.02896,
    BAM: 0.03457,
    BBD: 0.0344,
    BDT: 1.7593,
    BGN: 0.03457,
    BHD: 0.006468,
    BIF: 33.7214
  }
};

document.body.innerHTML = Object.entries(result["data"])
  .map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v}<br/>`)
  .join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it formatted perfectly in different lines using the following code.

```
 $('#exchangedata').html(JSON.stringify(result['data'],null, 4).replace(/['"]+/g, '').slice(1,-1).split(",").join("<br /><hr/>")
```

The .replace() regex helped to remove all the double quotes inside the json data
and .slice() helped with removing the curly braces from first and last index of data.
and split()and join () helped to remove the "," and place a line break after every currency